# "Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited." where EnableDocumentFunction set to true?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, xslt

I am getting an intermittent System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException exception in our production environment when attempting an xslt transform, unfortunately I cannot replicate this in the development environment.

The exception spits out further details:

> Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the
>   XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error
>   occurred at C:\path\to\file\CDS.xsl(16,3).

However the EnableDocumentFunction property *is* set to true in the processing code:

```
private void Transform()
{
    var keepTrying = true;
    var tryCount = 0;
    const int maxRetrys = 3;

    while (keepTrying)
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

            using (var xmlFile = new XmlNodeReader(_xDoc))
            {
                var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                                   {
                                       XmlResolver = xmlResolver,
                                       ProhibitDtd = false,
                                       DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
                                   };

                using (var xsl = XmlReader.Create(_xslPath, settings))
                {
                    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
                    xslt.Load(xsl, new XsltSettings { EnableDocumentFunction = true }, xmlResolver);

                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xslt.OutputSettings))
                    {
                        xslt.Transform(xmlFile, null, writer, xmlResolver); // errors out here.
                    }

                    var xhtml = sb.ToString();
                    _transformedXml = xhtml;
                    _isTransformed = true;

                    xsl.Close();
                }
            }

            keepTrying = false;
        }
        catch (System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException ex)
        {
            ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "ExceptionLogging");

            tryCount++;
            if (tryCount > maxRetrys)
            {
                keepTrying = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The xslt file is provided by a third party and automatically updated, so rewriting it is not an option.  Here is the top of it, slightly modified for privacy reasons:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
     Interaction_550.xsl : 20110916
-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:example="http://www.example.com" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="D2DSeverityFilter"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="D2HSeverityFilter"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="DocumentationFilter"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:key name="d2d_sev_level-lookup" match="example:d2d_sev_level" use="@name"/>
  <xsl:key name="d2h_sev_level-lookup" match="example:d2h_sev_level" use="@name"/>
      <xsl:key name="d2l_sev_level-lookup" match="example:d2l_sev_level" use="@name"/>
      <xsl:key name="preg_cat-lookup" match="example:preg_cat" use="@cat"/>
  <xsl:key name="doc_level-lookup" match="example:doc_level" use="@name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="d2d_sev_level-top" select="document('')/*/example:d2d_sev_levels"/>
  <xsl:variable name="d2h_sev_level-top" select="document('')/*/example:d2h_sev_levels"/>
      <xsl:variable name="d2l_sev_level-top" select="document('')/*/example:d2l_sev_levels"/>

  <xsl:variable name="doc_level-top" select="document('')/*/example:doc_levels"/>
      <xsl:variable name="preg_cat-top" select="document('')/*/example:preg_cats"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
body {
font-family : arial,sans serif,helvetica;
}
...
```

How can I:

- fix this so that it does not happen at all?
- failing that, how could I go about replicating this in dev?

Comment: The `document('')` function may fail if the stylesheet is in memory (cached) or if the resolver doesn't know how to process an empty-string URL. In case you have caching in the production version, this may be exactly the case. You may process programmatically the stylesheet into another one, that doesn't contain `document()` calls and that will execute successfully with XslCompiledTransform. In case that such a solution is of interest to you, please, do let me know and I can describe it in a reply.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I will start by verifying the caching situation - but it would be great if you could further describe processing the style sheet to remove the `document()` calls.

Comment: @_CamM: Yes, I posted an answer that contains a general transformation that does this required conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a general way to get rid of the `document('')/*/someName` expressions**:

The original transformation is processed with a special transformation that generates an equivalent transformation that doesn't contain the `document('')` function call.

Then you just need to use the generated transformation.

**Example**:

This transformation (lets name it `tA`), containing `document('')`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:paramDoc1>
  <x>123</x>
  <y>37</y>
 </my:paramDoc1>

 <my:paramDoc2>
  <x>456</x>
  <y>79</y>
 </my:paramDoc2>

 <xsl:variable name="vpDoc1" select="document('')/*/my:paramDoc1"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vpDoc2" select="document('')/*/my:paramDoc2"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vpDoc1/x"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="$vpDoc2/y"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any document, produces**:

```
123|79
```

**Now we process the above transformation with this one (`tGen`)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="a:a" exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="x"
      result-prefix="xsl"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSelectPrefix" select=
  "concat('document(', $vApos,$vApos, ')/*/')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <x:stylesheet xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </x:stylesheet>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xsl:variable">
  <xsl:variable name="vSelattr" select="@select"/>
  <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(starts-with(@select, $vSelectPrefix))">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      <x:variable name="vrtf{@name}">
        <xsl:copy-of select=
        "/*/*[name()
             = substring-after($vSelattr, $vSelectPrefix)
             ]"/>
      </x:variable>

      <x:variable name="{@name}" select=
           "ext:node-set($vrtf{@name})/*"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The result is a new transformation (`tRes`), which doesn't contain expressions like `document('')`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
         indent="yes" xmlns:my="my:my" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" xmlns:my="my:my" />
    <my:paramDoc1 xmlns:my="my:my">
        <x>123</x>
        <y>37</y>
    </my:paramDoc1>
    <my:paramDoc2 xmlns:my="my:my">
        <x>456</x>
        <y>79</y>
    </my:paramDoc2>
    <xsl:variable name="vrtfvpDoc1">
        <my:paramDoc1 xmlns:my="my:my">
            <x>123</x>
            <y>37</y>
        </my:paramDoc1>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vpDoc1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfvpDoc1)/*" />
    <xsl:variable name="vrtfvpDoc2">
        <my:paramDoc2 xmlns:my="my:my">
            <x>456</x>
            <y>79</y>
        </my:paramDoc2>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vpDoc2" select="ext:node-set($vrtfvpDoc2)/*" />
    <xsl:template match="/*" xmlns:my="my:my">
        <xsl:value-of select="$vpDoc1/x" />
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vpDoc2/y" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**If we now apply this dynamically generated transformation (`tRes`) to any XML document, the result is exactly the same** as when applying the original transformation (`tA`) to this document:

```
123|79
```

**Therefore, we can use `tGen` to convert a transformation containing `document('')` expressions to an equivalent transformation that doesn't contain such expressions**.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, the transform you provided has fixed the document() issue.  It also exposed that the full xslt was producing an invalid xml document (two root elements), which we have now also fixed - but I can't help but wonder if the two were internally related.

Comment: @CamM: Glad my answer helped. As for your question, the error message and the fact that not a wellformed document was generated -- these don't seem to be strongly related.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively with MS XslCompiledTransform class you can use a XsltSettings class to avoid this error as it described by the error itself. [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163499.aspx)

Comment: As stated in the original question "However the EnableDocumentFunction property is set to true in the processing code:", this was tried.